# Internet speed is reduced when using spotflux

Tags: vpn, internet

My internet speed is reduced to about 100 KBps when connected with spotflux VPN nowadays. My real speed is 1MBps. But when i used spotflux before 1 year there was no problem, It gave about same speed as the network has.

The only reason i used spotflux till now because torrents are blocked in the network. 
Is there any solution to increase the speed ?

Comment: Try [spotflux support](https://spotflux.zendesk.com/hc/en-us)

Comment: Do you pay them for premium service?